# Problems with making background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on this project but I would like for the background to be also around the profile div. [this is it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUKJp.png)

this is the HTML

```
<div class="content">
            <div class="profile">
                <h4>Jay</h4>
                <img src="default.jpg" width="125">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <h2>Test</h2>
                <p>hello guys hehe</p>
            </div>
</div>
```

and this is the CSS

```
.content{
    background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    padding: 10px;
}

.profile{
    background-color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Sorry if I explained it badly. English isn't my first language.

I tried looking it up on internet but I couldn't find it. It was most likely due my poor describing skills.

```css
.content {
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  padding: 10px;
}

.profile {
  background-color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="profile">
    <h4>Jay</h4>
    <img src="default.jpg" width="125">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <p>hello guys hehe</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which background? You have two: one is `rgb(100, 100, 100)` and should cover the `<div class="profile">`; the other is `rgb(200, 200, 200)` and should cover every other element.

Comment: the rgb(200, 200, 200) which should cover the background including the .profile

Comment: Why do you have `background-color: rgb(180, 180, 180);` in the rule for `.profile` if you want the background to be `rgb(200, 200, 200);`?

Comment: Short anwser: Aesthetic. The .profile is a div inside another one and i want to make sure that its visible well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flexbox instead of floats.

```css
.content.main {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  padding: 10px;
}

.profile {
  background-color: rgb(180, 180, 180);
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content main">
  <div class="profile">
    <h4>Jay</h4>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" width="125">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Test</h2>
    <p>hello guys hehe</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How does using flexbox change anything with the backgrounds?

Comment: @HereticMonkey You can see the issue with floating here: https://jsfiddle.net/4a90be2h/